# Error 419 while call Axios post in localhost but work when i change to ip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a simple call in my react apps. When i hit call axios on localhost:3000 it is shown an error Axios error 419 unknown status when i change to ip like 127.0.0.1 it is succes. How can i run normally with localhost:3000?

```
const jsonInvoice = {
    Email: "test@mail.com",
    PID: "2",
    RefNo: "012200254",
    amount: 10,
    ccy: "USD",
    description: "test",
    send_email: "true",
    userid: "test",
  };

  let urlEoffice = "https://test.url/";

  let configData = {
    method: "POST",
    url: urlEoffice + "invoice/create",
    data: jsonInvoice,
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await axios(configData).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        setResponseD(response.data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Test</p>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>tes</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely to be caused by localhost resolving to an IPV6 address, where 127.0.0.1 is an IPV4 address.  To confirm this, type `ping localhost`.  If you're running Windows and see output that looks like `Reply from ::1: time<1ms` rather than `Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128`, then that's likely your culprit.

If you can make your local service respond to IPV6 requests, then that's probably your safest and most widely compatible fix.  Assuming you're running Windows 10 or Windows 11, and you *REALLY* want `localhost` to be equivalent to `127.0.0.1`, then you could tell the operating system to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 by elevating the priority of IPv4 in the IPv6 prefix policies.  You would do so by increasing the precedence value of the policy matching `::ffff:0:0/96`.  I'll include instructions below, but understand this could cause unwanted effects in some other app you use down the road which could perform optimally under IPv6 but might fall back to IPv4 on your system due to this change.

1. Run a command prompt as Administrator.
2. Type `netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies`

(You should expect to see output similar to below)

```
   Querying active state...

   Precedence  Label  Prefix    
           50      0  ::1/128
           40      1  ::/0
           35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
           30      2  2002::/16
            5      5  2001::/32
            3     13  fc00::/7
            1     11  fec0::/10
            1     12  3ffe::/16
            1      3  ::/96
```

3. Type `netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 60 4`

That should take effect immediately.  You can verify by pinging localhost and should expect to see `127.0.0.1` in the output.

If you need to put your system back to its original priorities, you would open an escalated command prompt and key in the following:

`netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 35 4`

That would lower the `Precedence` value back from 60 to its original value of 35.